# How to find the maximum value for the given $x\cos{\lambda}+y\sin{\lambda}$?

Tags: trigonometry

How do I find the maximum value for $x\cos {λ}+y\sin {λ}$ for fixed $x,y$ and varying $λ$ ? I would appreciate if only hint is given.

Comment: Do differentiation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x\cos\lambda+y\sin\lambda $ is the dot product between $(x,y)$ and $(\cos\lambda,\sin\lambda)$, i.e. the product of the lengths times the cosine of the angle between these two vectors:

$$ x\cos\lambda + y\sin\lambda = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cos\left(\lambda-\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

Using [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity)  $$(x\cos A+y\sin A)^2+(x\sin A-y\cos A)^2=\cdots=x^2+y^2$$

Now for real $x,y,A;  (x\sin A-y\cos A)^2\ge0$

$$\implies(x\cos A+y\sin A)^2\le x^2+y^2$$

The equality occurs if $x\sin A-y\cos A=0$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Let $x\cos A+y\sin A=u$

Use  [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)  to form a Quadratic Equation in $\tan\dfrac A2$

As $A$ is real, so will be $\tan\dfrac A2$

So, the discriminant must be non-negative

Answer (score 1):

Write $x=r\sin t, y=r\cos t$ so that $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and $\tan t=\frac xy$ - so you can compute $r$ and $t$.

Then use the formula for $\sin (A+B)$ and your knowledge of trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 1):

For $v=x\cos{\lambda}+y\sin{\lambda}$

Do differentiation and you get:

$$\frac{dv}{d\lambda}=-x\sin\lambda+y\cos\lambda=0$$
$$\frac yx=\tan\lambda\implies\lambda=\tan^{-1}(\frac yx)$$

Draw a right-angled triangle with base $=x$ and opposite side$=y$ in respect to $\lambda$, we get the hypotenuse as $x\cos{\lambda}+y\sin{\lambda}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

[image]